# Error connecting to SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I saw all threads regarding this query in stack overflow. But I Can't find any solution

In the morning when I was trying one project on Visual studio 2010 it was working perfectly fine and now after restart  while running Visual studio project I get this error and even my SQL Server 2012 is not connecting what must be the problem ?

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Is your SQL server instance running?

Answer (score 0):

I found Solution to this problem . i'm Instance was proper but TCP/IP was disabled

Go to SQL server configuration tool and open sql server configuration manager . Click on the instance you want to change . Click on protocols and then enable TCP/IP . IT works fine now :)